# MFC MDI OutputWnd.cpp Context popup in COutputList "Hide" not working due to NULL Pointer

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2017, mfc, contextmenu

I'm doing some final cleanup in my code for straggler functions. My output pane is taken directly from the out of the box `OutputWnd.cpp` created by the MFC wizard. When you right click on the output pane with the 3 tabs it creates, the context options are copy/clear/hide. I have copy and clear working. But the issue is the `Hide`. When clicked, it drops into the function `void COutputList::OnViewOutput()` and I've debugged it to verify it drops into it.

Here is the function:

```
void COutputList::OnViewOutput()
{
    CDockablePane* pParentBar = DYNAMIC_DOWNCAST(CDockablePane, GetOwner());
    CMDIFrameWndEx* pMainFrame = DYNAMIC_DOWNCAST(CMDIFrameWndEx, GetTopLevelFrame());

    if (pMainFrame != nullptr && pParentBar != nullptr)
    {
        pMainFrame->SetFocus();
        pMainFrame->ShowPane(pParentBar, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE);
        pMainFrame->RecalcLayout();
    }
}
```

So debugging it, the logic says as long as `pParentBar` and `PMainFrame` isn't a `nullptr`, then hide the output pane.

What IS happening is that `pMainFrame` is OK but `pParentBar` is coming back as `nullptr` and therefore the pane never hides. I've tried this extensively in my app and even went back to building the default project wizard in `VS2017` and testing it there UNMODIFIED and even the out of the box solution doesn't work.

I've looked all over Google and every example has the same exact function as above without any modification...which tells me, no one really cares it doesn't work. Well I'd like to make it work, but I'm not sure why the `GetOwner()` is returning a `nullptr`. I would "expect" that MS would give us some properly working code since it did everything within the function generation to make it work. This is like playing `Where's Waldo`....in code.

Anyone have any idea how to fix that piece or what may be erroneous in the out of the box code?

Thanks.

## Update:

Based on IInspectable's question of was it `DYNAMIC_DOWNCAST` or `GetOwner()` I stepped into the function and found that it is an `_AFXWIN_INLINE` and this is the function that is being used to decide the owner:

```
_AFXWIN_INLINE CWnd* CWnd::GetOwner() const
    { return m_hWndOwner != NULL ? CWnd::FromHandle(m_hWndOwner) : GetParent(); }
```

Seems like a simple true/false to determine how to `GetOwner` so I chopped it directly both true and false to see if either would return anything like so:

```
CDockablePane*  pParentBar = DYNAMIC_DOWNCAST(CDockablePane, GetParent());
```

and

```
CDockablePane*  pParentBar = DYNAMIC_DOWNCAST(CDockablePane, CWnd::FromHandle(m_hWndOwner);
```

Both returned a NULL, I'm am not entirely sure how to break apart the `DYNAMIC_DOWNCAST` since it is a pointer to pointer function. I did `delete` the `DYNAMIC_DOWNCAST` but that just created more issues with compiling.

I also tried to remove the if condition of `pParentBar`, but of course without the handle, the app crashes when you try to execute the hide.

Open to suggestions on how to continue to troubleshoot this.

Comment: Does `GetOwner()` return a NULL pointer, or is it the [DYNAMIC_DOWNCAST](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/mfc/reference/type-casting-of-mfc-class-objects#dynamic_downcast)?

Comment: I updated my original post based on your question.

Comment: Perhaps you can create a test project and provide a link to it?

Comment: Ordinary-Developer below outline exactly how I created the project and then was able to rewrite the function in question and it is working as expected now. Thanks to all!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### An attempt to explaining this behaviour

Yes, you're right.

If we create a simple project (based on the *"MFC App"* template with *"Project Style"* as *"Visual Studio"* and *"Visual Style and Colors"* as *"Visual Studio 2008"*), then

> even the out of the box solution doesn't work.

Why is this happening?
In the next code when the `COutputList` members are created

```cpp
...
if (!m_wndOutputBuild.Create(dwStyle, rectDummy, &m_wndTabs, 2) ||
    !m_wndOutputDebug.Create(dwStyle, rectDummy, &m_wndTabs, 3) ||
    !m_wndOutputFind.Create(dwStyle, rectDummy, &m_wndTabs, 4))
{
    TRACE0("Failed to create output windows\n");
    return -1;      // fail to create
}
...
```

there is reason to believe that our *COutputList*'s `GetOwner()` function will return the pointer to `m_wndTabs` member which is `CMFCTabCtrl` instance, so if we write in `COutputList::OnViewOutput()` something like this:

```cpp
CMFCTabCtrl * pParentTabCtrl = DYNAMIC_DOWNCAST(CMFCTabCtrl, GetOwner());
```

then `pParentTabCtrl` will not be equal to nullptr.

But I don't know how to get a `CDockablePane` instance from a `CMFCTabCtrl` instance (different `GetTabWnd` and so on don't work (at least for me), and search with Google and search through MFCinternals also yielded no results).

**Once again:** *Maybe there are ways to get a `CDockablePane`  from `CMFCTabCtrl`, but now I don't know them.*

---

#### Proposed solution

So, the only solution I can offer is to make the member:

```cpp
COutputWnd        m_wndOutput;
```

*public* in the `CMainFrame` class (or make `CMainFrame` as a *'friend'* for the `COuputList` - here it is more or less the same).

And then implement the `COutputList::OnViewOutput()` something like this:

```cpp
void COutputList::OnViewOutput()
{
    if (CMainFrame* pMainFrame = dynamic_cast<CMainFrame*>(GetTopLevelFrame())) {
        if (CDockablePane* pOutputWnd = dynamic_cast<CDockablePane*>(&pMainFrame->m_wndOutput)) {
            pMainFrame->SetFocus();
            pMainFrame->ShowPane(pOutputWnd, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE);
            pMainFrame->RecalcLayout();
        }
    }
}
```

Of course, this is not a true MFC-way solution, but at least it works.

Comment: Glad to see I'm not nuts! Your rewrite of the `void COutputList::OnViewOutput()` works great. I already had `COutputWnd        m_wndOutput;` public for another aspect of the program. This solved my problem and it works great! Thanks for taking the time to help me with this. Hopefully it will help others as well if they decide to use this canned solution. All the best.